# Need PowerShell script for display the output of powershell script to outbox in powershell forms

Tags: powershell

I am trying to display the powershell outputs in outbox of powershell forms. But it showing blank. not output data is showing in outbox. but here I used for output variable as $result. In that output variable the excepted result is available. Only thing I cannot display the output in outbox of powershell forms.

```
# Load required assemblies
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

# Create Form to contain elements
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

# Set Form Titlebar text
$Form.Text = "AD ACCOUNT LOCKOUT FINDER"

# Set size of form
# Size(<length>,<height>) in pixels
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600,600)

# Create an Input textbox
$inputBoxgmr = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$inputBoxgmr.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(30,50)
$inputBoxgmr.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)

# Initialize the textbox inside the Form
$Form.Controls.Add($inputBoxgmr)

# Create Instruction Label for inputBox
$Labelgmr = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Labelgmr.Text = "Enter Domain User ID"
$Labelgmr.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(30,30)
$Labelgmr.BackColor = "Transparent"
$Labelgmr.AutoSize = $true

# Add a Button which can be used to generate an action from our textboxes
$Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,45)
$Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80,30)
$Button.Text = "FIND"

# Declare the action to occur when button clicked
$Button.Add_Click( { find } )

# Initialize the button inside the Form
$Form.Controls.Add($Button)

# Create a Function to make use of textboxes
function find {

  #$outputBox.Clear()

  $Results = Import-Csv -Path "D:\Excel\Data\List.csv" -Header "EventID", "TimeCreated", "Computer", "TargetUserName", "SubjectUserName", "HOSTName", "Filename" | 
        Where-Object {$_.TargetUserName -eq "inputBoxgmr"} | 
        Select-Object "EventID", "TimeCreated", "Computer", "TargetUserName", "SubjectUserName", "HOSTName", "Filename" 

  
  # Assign Result to OutputBox
  $outputBox.Text = $Results

  # Clear OutputBox
  $inputBoxgmr.Clear()
}



# Create an Output textbox, 10 pixels in from Form Boundary and 150 pixels down
# As we want a multiline output set textbox size to 565 px x 200 px
# .Multiline declares the textbox is multi-line
$outputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$outputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,100)
$outputBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(565,450)
$outputBox.MultiLine = $True
$outputBox.Scrollbars = "Vertical"

# Initialize the textbox inside the Form
$Form.Controls.Add($OutputBox)


# Initialize Label
$Form.Controls.Add($Labelgmr)

# Initialize form and show it
# [void] used to suppress other messages generated by Form actions
[void] $Form.ShowDialog()
```

Output forms
[image: Output forms]

Excel input data
[image: Excel input data]

output variables
[image: output variables]

Comment: The textbox is expecting a string, converting $results to JSON or CSV shows the results in the textbox. For example, add the line $results | convertto-json before $outputBox.Text = $Results. Basically, you need to pass a string to the textbox.

Comment: Sorry, The output result is not in $Results. Kindly help me @nimizen

Comment: @Arunkumar user outpotbox not  text box  to  $outputBox=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid and $array.Addrange($results) and $outputbox.Datasource = ($array) wil be show your results